# How to access elements of modal using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[Modal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSguE.png)

PageObject Modal file: where I get all the paths

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
class LoginPage:
    
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    LoginField  = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='outlined-number']")
    LoginButton = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='welcome-login']/div/button")
    SocialLogin  = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='welcome-login']/button")
    OTPMsg = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Toastify__toast-body']/div/div")
    Verify = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='d-flex justify-content-between gap-10']//button[contains(text(), 'Verify')]")
    AddOTPText = (By.XPATH, "//h5[@class='font-bold']")
    ResendOTP = (By.XPATH, "//h6[contains(text(),'Resend')]")
    # OTPSuccess = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='alert']:nth-child(1)")
    EnterOTPText = (By.XPATH, "//h6[contains(text(),'Please enter the OTP sent to your mobile number +9')]")

                 


    def getNumber(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.LoginField)
    
    def clickLoginButton(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.LoginButton)
    
    def clickSocialLogin(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.SocialLogin).click()
    
    def getOTPMsg(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.OTPMsg)
    
    def clickVerify(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.Verify).click()
    
    def getAddOTPText(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.AddOTPText)
    
    def clickResendOTP(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.ResendOTP).click()
    
    def getEnterOTPText(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.EnterOTPText)
    
    # def getOTPSuccess(self):
    #     return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.OTPSuccess)
```

BaseClass File: Where generic functions are written

```
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from pageobject.HomePage import HomePage

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseClass:
    def verifyPresence(self, path):
         WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(path)
            )
         
    def closePopup(self):
     homepage = HomePage(self.driver)
     try:
          self.verifyPresence(homepage.CloseButton)
          homepage.Close_Button().click()
     except:
         print("Close")

    def verifyInvisibility(self,path):
         WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
              EC.invisibility_of_element_located(path)
              )
```

TestCase file: THis is the main testcase file

```
from typing import KeysView
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from TestData.LoginData import LoginData
from pageobject.HomePage import HomePage
from pageobject.LoginPage import LoginPage
# from TestData.LoginData import LoginData 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass

# @pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")

@pytest.fixture(params=LoginData.test_login_data)
def getData(request):
    return request.param

class TestLogin(BaseClass):
    OTP_TEXT  = "OTP is not correct"
    OTP_SUCCESS = "OTP sent successfully"
    # @pytest.mark.skip
    def test_login(self, getData):
        homepage = HomePage(self.driver)
        loginpage = LoginPage(self.driver)
        if not hasattr(TestLogin, 'actions_done'):
            self.closePopup()
            homepage.ClickLogin()
            TestLogin.actions_done = True
        
        loginpage.getNumber().send_keys(getData["phone"])
        input_value = loginpage.getNumber().get_attribute("value")
        integer_value = int(input_value)
        OTPtext = loginpage.getOTPMsg()
        OTPSuccess = loginpage.getOTPSuccess()
        enable = loginpage.clickLoginButton().is_enabled()
        if(integer_value==54646 or integer_value==357657):
            assert not enable
        if(integer_value==3237574584):
            assert enable
            loginpage.clickLoginButton().click()
            self.verifyPresence(LoginPage.OTPSuccess)
            assert OTPSuccess == self.OTP_SUCCESS
            # loginpage.clickVerify()
            # self.verifyPresence(LoginPage.OTPMsg)
            # assert OTPtext == self.OTP_TEXT
            loginpage.clickResendOTP()
            self.verifyPresence(LoginPage.OTPSuccess)
            assert OTPSuccess == self.OTP_SUCCESS
            self.verifyInvisibility(loginpage.Verify)



        print(input_value)
        
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.refresh()
    @pytest.mark.skip
    def test_social_login(self):
        homepage = HomePage(self.driver)
        loginpage = LoginPage(self.driver)
        if not hasattr(TestLogin, 'actions_done'):
            self.closePopup()
            homepage.ClickLogin()
            TestLogin.actions_done = True
        
        loginpage.clickSocialLogin()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        MainWindow = self.driver.window_handles[0]
        New_Window = self.driver.window_handles[1]
        self.driver.switch_to.window(New_Window)
        sleep(1)
```

When I run this code, I does not pick elements of modal and give error that *Unable to locate element*. I have not found any solution for this. I did not understand why its not getting paths. How can I do that.
**Note: This is not an Iframe**